# Conventions for Swift protocols

Tags: swift, unit-testing, naming, swift-protocols

I have a class called `NetworkInterface` - and I want to make this class testable. The way to do this in Swift means I should extract a protocol from it? My quandry is, what do I call this protocol? I don't want to call it `NetworkInterface` as that then takes the 'good name' for the protocol and then what would I call my `NetworkInterface` class? I've seen a pattern where people give the protocol the nice name and then call the class something horrible like `DefaultNetworkInterface` but I don't like this either.

Should I call the protocol `NetworkInterfaceProtocol` and then the class `NetworkInterface`? What would be conventional here?

Here is the code I have so far, but I'm not convinced my names are conventional.

```swift
protocol NetworkInterfaceProtocol {
    func ip4() -> String?
}

struct NetworkInterface: NetworkInterfaceProtocol {
    let interfaceName: String

    func ip4() -> String? {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Naming protocols can be hard, specially in a situation like this when you already have a meaningful name. I have some generic words I use to add at the end if I can’t come up with a unique name like “Service” or “Support”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only convention for protocol naming by Swift.org is to use **noun**, **`able`**, **`ible`** or **`ing`** where applicable. [**reference here**](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#protocols-describing-what-is-should-read-as-nouns)

So one practice is to break down the entity into smaller *describable* parts and name them like:

```
protocol IP4Representable {
    func ip4() -> String?
}

protocol IP6Representable {
    func ip6() -> String?
}
```

And then using it like:

```
extension NetworkInterface: IP4Representable & IP6Representable { ... }
```

You can also merge them in the way the `Codable` does like:

```
typealias IPRepresentable = IP4Representable & IP6Representable

extension NetworkInterface: IPRepresentable { ... }
```

Indeed you can have bigger chunks based on the needs and it does not have to be a 'single function only' in each protocol.

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks, however thr protocol I wish to abstract is really a full network interface, it has other methods like interfaceName and macAddress etc, can you think of an appropriate protocol name in this case ? `NetworkInterface~ is all I csn come up with, but that takes the good name from the class...so in that case what should I call the class?

Comment: This practice is a general approach that you can use in any situation. For your specific case, maybe using `NetworkInterface` as the protocol and `Wireless`, `fiber` etc as the class names. Or one step backward and use a simple subclassing for the test instead of POP. At the end of the day, each method has its own cons and pros.